# Zener diode and resistor for voltage regulator

Tags: voltage, diodes, voltage-regulator, zener

How should I choose Zener diode and resistor to protect it for voltage regulator? Let's say I've got 9V battery and want to get stable 5V output even when battery starts to discharge and it gives only 8V voltage? I tried to calculate it, but every time I do it I get an errors in equations.

Comment: Can you please show your calculations in order to comment them? Also state any assumptions you made, and what you know about each component (max current, max wattage etc).

Comment: And *how much current* is needed.

Comment: And have you considered a linear regulator/LDO instead of a resistor/zener combination?

Comment: How about this: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_7.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zener diode as voltage regulator and problem with I Kirchoff's Law](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570229/zener-diode-as-voltage-regulator-and-problem-with-i-kirchoffs-law)

Comment: This is virtually identical to your previous questions, which has some useful answers. Not cool.

Answer (score 4):

Forget the Zener and use an LDO (low-dropout) regulator instead. This will be more efficient than using the Zener as a shunt regulator. LDO's are common and inexpensive these days.

If you want even more efficiency or need higher current, consider using a DCDC step-down. There are even DCDC modules that fit the uA7805 TO-220 pinout that drop right in.

Answer (score 2):

Given your earlier Zener regulator questions it might help to play around with this Falstad simulation:

[(5.6V DC Zener Falstad simulation)](https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAQBYKLIKBTAWjDACgAlETFcQulFNTB8ooynWKi6MBKwBeIbNkJc8eRct51sIACb0AZgEMArgBsALozn0AdvQBOrAOYaVKNW8WRq01gHcvYTpKYS0oVgcQUJVg6LCPdX54F3j3TxjvXwio7nClWJE6BDhWAHtRQmzxYnUwaVhIbDAUJH5RHQBLW3LokCqxSFrkKEam4khCVvAuPp0ykwteiAGQocl60bgppB4eCB0beycgA)

The Zener voltage in this circuit is about 5.6V.

With the supply set at 9V and a 500 ohm series resistor, the current for this regulator is set to (9-5.6)/500 = 6.8 mA.

The keys things to note are:

1. If the load draws too much current then no current goes through the Zener
2. Otherwise, the voltage across the Zener stays about 5.6V

Modify the load resistor value to see how it changes things.

Some example resistor values to experiment with:

| R_Load | I_Load | I_Z | I_Load + I_Z | R_Load *I_Load |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3K | 1.9 mA | 4.9 mA | 6.8 mA | 5.7 V |
| 2K | 2.8 mA | 4.0 mA | 6.8 mA | 5.6 V |
| 1K | 5.5 mA | 1.3 mA | 6.8 mA | 5.5 V |
| 600 | 8.1 mA | 0 mA | 8.1 mA | 4.86 V |
| 300 | 11.3 mA | 0 mA | 11.3 mA | 3.39 V |

In the first three cases there is current going through the Zener and I_Z + I_R always equals 6.8 mA and R_Load*I_Load is close to 5.6V.

But in the last two cases there is no Zener current and also no regulation.

If there's no current going through the Zener, the circuit behaves as if the Zener wasn't there (for the purpose of this analysis). Essentially you can remove it from the circuit. This would leave just a voltage divider with the two resistors.

In this circuit the critical R_Load value is about 833 ohms. That's where the Zener current hits zero because R_Load  carries all of the 6.8 mA.